# JQuery idletimer not firing on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, idle-timer

Using the lovely Jquery idletimer from https://github.com/thorst/jquery-idletimer: seems I cannot attach the idle timer to a specific element (as opposed to the whole document).  Here is my very simple code:

To fire the idle timer:

```
$("#testme"  ).on( "idle.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj){ $("#test").html("now idle");});
$( "#testme" ).on( "active.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj, triggerevent){ $("#test").html("not idle");});
$( "#testme" ).idleTimer(3000);
```

To invoke it in the document:

```
<div id="testme" style="border: solid;"><p id="test">I am idle</p></div>
```

Here's the thing.  If I replace $("#testme"  ) with $(document) it works fine.  But not when it is attached to a div element.  I am using jquery-1.11.0.js, jquery.mobile-1.4.2 and idle-timer.js.

Update: I now have a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/peterrr73/C3w7f/ which shows this half-working, on attachment to an element.  As the fiddle shows: the idle fires; then the active fires -- but there it stops, for some reason.  Thanks to  Jeromy French for helping out with jsFiddle; he has this working with a whole document, but not an element, at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/2aGL4/12/.

Comment: Hmm...which browser are you using? And why are you attaching to an element (I see that you *can*, I'm just wondering if maybe you're dynamically attaching the element)...

Comment: Using Chrome.  Have not tested this in other browsers. The reason for attaching it to an element is I have other muck on the page which I don't want to invoke the idler.  I am using the idler to hide/show footer and header elements in JQM.  Works fine.  Except that when I am scrolling a particular element on the page I do not want the footer/header to appear, so I don't want the idler working on that element.  Thought I could do this by attaching the idler to another element

Comment: It seems that idle timeout is only valid for `document` and not for any `elements`

Comment: Yes, I guessed that.  But the demo at [http://thorst.github.io/jquery-idletimer/index.html](http://thorst.github.io/jquery-idletimer/index.html) does attach the idler to a textarea element and it works (so I tried doing the same, attaching to a text area element, no luck..)

Comment: And, I am not dynamically attaching the element...

Comment: Can you create a JSFIddle?

Comment: OK, will try to do this.  Never done it. Always a first time...

Comment: Jfiddle does not seem to play with this.  But you can see the code working at [http://www.sd-editions.com/CantApp/index2.html](http://www.sd-editions.com/CantApp/index2.html) with 'document' and failing at [http://www.sd-editions.com/CantApp/index3.html](http://www.sd-editions.com/CantApp/index3.html) with attachment to an element

Comment: Yeah, even the baseline fiddle from the project's notes wasn't working. I fixed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/2aGL4/12/

Comment: Can you layer your example on top of that fiddle?

Comment: OK! now in jfiddle, at [http://jsfiddle.net/peterrr73/C3w7f/](http://jsfiddle.net/peterrr73/C3w7f/).  It is half working, which is better: that is, the idle comes on the first time, then goes off when there is activity within the element -- and then, it does NOT detect further inactivity within the element

Answer (score 0):

This is now working..
see http://jsfiddle.net/peterrr73/C3w7f/3, with two separate div elements, each responding only to events within that div:

```
<div id="testme" style="border: solid;"><p id="test">I am idle</p></div>
<div id="testme2" style="border: solid;"><p id="test2">I am idle</p></div> 

(function ($) {    
   $("#testme"  ).on( "idle.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj){ $("#test").html("I am very idle");});
   $( "#testme"  ).on( "active.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj, triggerevent){ $("#test").html("not idle");});
   $( "#testme" ).idleTimer(3000);
   $("#testme2"  ).on( "idle.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj){ $("#test2").html("I am very idle");});
   $( "#testme2"  ).on( "active.idleTimer", function(event, elem, obj, triggerevent){ $("#test2").html("not idle");});
    $( "#testme2" ).idleTimer(3000);
 })(jQuery);
```

Not sure why it was not working... It works fine both if you wrap the timer statements in  (function ($) {      })(jQuery); and if you do not.